# SignalR, WPF server doesn't start if not run as administrator

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr

We are updating our existing Windows desktop software with signalR instead of original WCF. 
At the beginning of learning SignalR we have problem with server which starts well with the uri `http://localhost:8080` but if I use the `http://*:8080` or `http://MyIPServer:8080` it doesn't work until I run the program under admin.

When running normally without admin rights, I have an error in the `webApp.start` (an exception occurs, nothing more!).

I've added a filter rule in the Windows firewall to accept all `8080` port inbound, but without much more success

The code is simple (it is from the Microsoft sample):

```c#
   const string ServerURI = "http://localhost:8080";
   private void StartServer()
        {
            try
            {
                SignalR = WebApp.Start(ServerURI);
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
            {
                WriteToConsole("A server error: " + ex.Message );
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ButtonStart.IsEnabled = true);
                return;
            }
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ButtonStop.IsEnabled = true);
            WriteToConsole("Server started at " + ServerURI);
        }
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at URL ACL. You can provide the rights to start a server like this on the command line:

```
netsh http add urlacl http://+:8080/ user=Everyone
```

You can use *Everyone* (must be localized!) or a specific user.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, but is there another standard method to run server without admin right and using the server name or '*' ? Because running a command line is not the easiest way for a Windows application to download and install for any customer... ;)

Comment: At least the installer must be run with admin rights and perform this operation (maybe silently or through some other way I do not know about). The Windows security policy does simply not allow anyone to open  a server service per default. This is a protection. In most cases such services run on servers where the setup is not that much of a problem.

Comment: Thank you ZoolWay, i did this on installer (InstallMate which is a good one) and it seems to do the job.